# What are "Dice Roll Groups" in D&D Beyond, and why are they useful?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dnd-beyond

What are D&D Beyond's Dice Roll Groups, as referred to in [this changelog post](https://www.dndbeyond.com/changelog/925-ability-score-dice-rolls), and why are they useful?

> [...]
>
> - When on the ABILITIES section of the Builder, and you select the “Manual/Rolled” option for ability score selection, You will now be
>   able to interact with the “Dice Roll Groups” collapsible UI. (if
>   Digital Dice is set to disabled when you arrive at this section, you
>   will see a prompt to enable Digital Dice which presents the  “Dice
>   Roll Groups” if enabled.
>
> The Dice Roll Groups UI:
>
> - ADD GROUP: allows you to create up to 10 groups of up to 6 rolls in each group.
> - RESET GROUP: resets the entire group as a whole
> - APPLY ABILITY SCORES: applies any scores that have been rolled and set ( rolls with totals but no Stat assigned do not unset any current
>   scores, but rolls with Stats assigned will overwrite any previously
>   assigned value)
> - DELETE GROUP: delete entire group

I can figure out what "delete a group" means, but why would you want to create a group in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I've used them for an alternate ability score generation method: "best of n attempts".

The traditional score generation method is 6 rolls of 4d6, dropping the lowest die from each set. I am typically okay with starting ability scores skewing a little bit higher, so I like to use a "best of" method. That is, roll the traditional way, but take your choice of 3 attempts. DDB's groups feature on the ability scores tab makes this simple. Create three groups and roll them up, and apply the group you want:

[image]

Comment: This is a great *example*, but to also be a great *answer* I think you need to put your use case in the context of "why would you want to create a group in the first place" and explain the benefits of doing this Vs any other method (even if it's obvious/very small change)